# C# data.fill (conversion failure)

Tags: c#, sql, type-conversion

Using C#, .NET 4, SQL, visual studio 2010 and sql server manager 2008.

Hi guys, Seems like that same old easy to solve 101 question, but something has been bugging me.

My program runs a query and grabs the data and fills a dataset.

One of my fields is called pg (product group) and is set to a nvarchar(255).
most of the pgs are numbers like 30,50,12 etc but there are exceptions to this such as T1B and 50a.

For some reason I'm getting a conversion error.

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'T1B' to an int".

In my code all I'm using is data.fill();

Is it me or does it seem as though the data.fill is trying to assign the field PG as an integer because the first records it pulls looks like an int?
To be honest I always thought the fill would mimic whatever the sql data types were to its equivalent.

Hopefully its something easy that im overlooking.

If you wish to see more code, let me know and i will edit this post.

Many thanks

SQL Query

```
USE [ShaftData]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetSalesParetotemp]    Script Date: 03/14/2012       09:30:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSalesParetotemp] 
@acct varchar(255), 
@From date, 
@Too date
AS
SELECT i.Acct,
   i.Name, 
   i.Document, 
   i.Part, 
   i.Qty, 
   i.Unit, 
   dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, 
   i.pg,
   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName,
   i.[DateTime]

FROM   
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.iHeads.acct,
                            dbo.iHeads.name,
                            dbo.iLines.Document,
                            dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            dbo.iLines.Qty,
                            dbo.iLines.unit,
                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime]  
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.iheads INNER JOIN     Autopart.dbo.iLines ON 
                     Autopart.dbo.Iheads.document =   autopart.dbo.iLines.document
                     GROUP By dbo.iHeads.acct,
                            dbo.iHeads.name,
                            dbo.iLines.Document,
                            dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            dbo.iLines.Qty,
                            dbo.iLines.unit,
                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime]
                      ') i
left JOIN
  dbo.NEWPareto
ON 
i.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.NEWPareto.Part 
left JOIN
dbo.MyPgTable 
ON  
  i.pg collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.MyPgTable.[pGroup]

WHERE
 (i.[DateTime] BETWEEN @From AND @Too) AND
 i.Acct = @acct 
 AND i.pg != 60
 AND i.pg != 61
 AND i.pg != 62

 GROUP BY i.Acct,
   i.Name, 
   i.Document, 
   i.Part, 
   i.Qty, 
   i.Unit, 
   dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, 
   i.pg,
   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName, 
   i.[DateTime]
```

And here's the method that calls it

```
try
        {
            string myConn = "Server=derp;" +
                            "Database=derp;" +
                            "uid=derp;" +
                            "pwd=derp;" +
                            "Connect Timeout=120;";

            string acct;// test using 1560

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConn);
            SqlCommand Pareto = new SqlCommand();
            BindingSource bindme = new BindingSource();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(Pareto);
            DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();

            acct = Acct;

            string fromDate = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            string tooDate = this.dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            Pareto.Connection = conn;
            Pareto.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Pareto.CommandText = "dbo.GetSalesParetotemp";
            Pareto.CommandTimeout = 120;

            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", acct);
            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", fromDate);
            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@too", tooDate);

            SetCheckBoxValue(true);
            SetPictureBoxVisibility(true);
            //label1.Visible = true;
            adapt1.Fill(dataSet1, "Pareto");
            //label1.Visible = false;
            SetCheckBoxValue(false);
            SetPictureBoxVisibility(false);

            SetDataGrid(true, dataSet1, "Pareto", DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);

            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
        }
        catch (Exception execc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Seems we couldnt connect to the server!"
                            + " information:\n\n" + execc.Message + execc.StackTrace,
                            "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste some relevant code? :)

Comment: no problem, here's the query and here's the method that uses it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's SQL error caused by the query itself, because it mentions 'varchar', and if it were a .Net issue it would be saying 'string'.

Specifically:

```
WHERE 
 (i.[DateTime] BETWEEN @From AND @Too) AND 
 i.Acct = @acct  
 AND i.pg != 60 
 AND i.pg != 61 
 AND i.pg != 62
```

That clause is breaking when it encounters one of the rows with the non-numeric `pg` value

You could just change them to strings - i.e. `'60'`, `'61'` and `'62'`

Comment: Holy derp i knew it was something simple i overlooked, pretty new to sql thanks for the advice! ill go try it and update you with the result